# AR, draw onto 3d surface using camera centre in python

Tags: python, opencv, gis, augmented-reality

I am unsure whether the following idea is feasible using freely available packages (OpenCV, PyGame etc.).

Goal:
To be able to interactively 'draw' onto uneven real-world 3D surfaces (e.g. the ground) constructed on the fly from a camera feed. The drawing would be done by touching the screen or by using a fixed point of the screen (e.g. the centre) as a cursor whilst moving the camera.

Work flow:

1. Build model: Walk around an area and use frames from camera feed to construct simple 3D model of visible surfaces (using COLMAP or other SfM software ?)
2. Draw on model: Use frames from camera to determine position of camera relative to 3D model (OpenCV ?). Project point on centre of camera screen to point on real world surface.

Appreciate the computational costs of constructing 3d model on the fly might slow the whole process - if this was pre-processed would step 2 still be feasible?

Comment: That will work. The challenging thing is to determine an "intuitive" way for a brush-surface-interaction as your drawing surface is 2d. You could just project, but this might feel a bit cheap.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend any libraries / packages / tutorials suitable for the various tasks outlined above?

Comment: Sorry, now. I just searched for sfm libraries and there are a handful for Python but I don't know how well they work. For the other task you might have to get into pure OpenGL (PyOpenGL) or VRED (https://www.pythonpeople.nl/python-and-vr/)